# Creating two separate websocket connections for send and receive on localhost

Tags: websocket, localhost

I am new to websockets.

It is expected to send data(any data) on the send websocket connection using some port(ex:8000) and the localhost should echo the same data to the browser using a different websocket connection through a different port(ex:9000).

I understand websocket supports full duplex communication on a single connection,but the above is the design to implement.

Question 1) Is the above design possible?
Question 2) If yes,how to create two websocket connections(one to send and one to receive) to a single localhost websocket server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) Creating two separated websockets. They will be different objects though.

You could blend both objects in a composite object like this:

```
var compositeWebSocket = function(urlSend, urlReceive){
    var me = {};
    var wsSend = new WebSocket(urlSend);
    var wsReceive = new WebSocket(urlReceive);
    var open = 0;

    wsSend.onopen = opening;
    wsReceive.onopen = opening;

    var opening = function(){
        if(open == 2){
            if(me.onopen)
                me.onopen();
        }
        else
            open++;
    };

    var closing = funcion(){
        try{wsSend.close();}catch(){}
        try{wsReceive.close();}catch(){}
        if(me.onclose)
            me.onclose();
    }

    me.send = wsSend.send;

    wsReceive.onmessage = function(msg){
        if(me.onmessage)
            me.onmessage(msg);
    }

    return me;
}
```

(Whatch out, this code is not tested and it is just an idea)

Comment: The idea is useful..How about the implementation on the server side.I think the localhost server should be listening at two ports.I am using nodejs+socket.io code for serverside implementation.

Comment: I have never used nodejs, but you should ensure you can pair the two connections by for example the a cookie.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to keep two separated connections? There is no benefit at all in that, just complications.

Comment: Thats a design decision taken by the architect based on the design of another part of the project(firmware).All I am supposed to do is to implement:(..And will upvote when I have 10 reputation:)